# Setting eventlisteners in private functions

Tags: javascript, dom-events

My case :

```
function C() {
        this.create = function() {
                var div=document.createElement("div");
                div.setAttribute("onclick","alert('this works')");
                div.onclick=function(){
                        alert("this doesnt work");
                }
                document.appendChild(div);
        }
        this.create();
}
var x = new C();
```

Is it not possible to set `onclick` event that way in JavaScript?
Should the function that is called should be globally defined? I can understand the problem that it is not globally defined, but I want to use the private variables within the function where I define the `onclick` event. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you've posted is almost [correct](http://jsbin.com/ibala4). Append the element to anything but the `document`, e.g.: `document.body`. Don't set event handlers with `setAttribute` because it's buggy.
You can use the `onclick` property or the W3C standard `addEventListener` method (`attachEvent` in IE).

```
function C() {
    this.create = function() {
        var div = document.createElement("div");
        div.innerHTML = "click me";
        var inner = "WORKS!";
        div.onclick = function(){
            alert(inner); // private variable is ok
        };
        document.body.appendChild(div);
        div = null; // avoid memory leak in IE
    };
    this.create();
}
var x = new C();
```

Answer (score 0):

What about

```
div.addEventListener('click', function() {
    alert('hello!');
}, false);
```

?

That way the function is anonymous and is only seen in the scope in which you're declaring it. It's not global.

Here's some API docs on addEventListener: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.addEventListener

Comment: I believe that to be the same with `div.onclick=function(){ alert("this doesnt work"); }` though -- which uses an annonymous function too.

Comment: Yes, but 'my' method allows you to add more than one listener. Assigning it with = just allows you to have one listener.